# Cannot show image converted in base64

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, base64

I'm trying to put a base64 string into an image view I've tried in many ways but is not working, so What I'm doing first is encode my string to base64, after that I'm trying to assign that base64 in to an image but when to block of code finish the line of code **qrCodeImageView.image = image** returns me nil, do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance

class QRCodeViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var qrCodeImageView: UIImageView!

var qrCodeConverted: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


        print("QRCode", APIManager.sharedInstance.bas64 ?? "")

    let longstring = APIManager.sharedInstance.qrCodee
    let data = (longstring)?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let base64 = data!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    print("base64 ", base64)

    if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
        let image = UIImage(data: decodedData)
        qrCodeImageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: is data returning nil?

Comment: I sense that your decoding options should be NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)

Comment: Is `image` is nil?

Comment: Yes is returning nil

Comment: Then your data is not a valid image format.

Comment: what is `APIManager.sharedInstance.bas64` and `APIManager.sharedInstance.qrCodee`? If you are okay can you please post sample data of those values?

Comment: Well, is the string that I'm converting in base64 it's a long string, do you want to see it? but APIManager.sharedInstance.bas64 is not valid now the string that I'm trying to convert is APIManager.sharedInstance.qrCodee like I said, it's a long string

Comment: Is a String that contains 10816 characters